# WPF ToolBar Item Rendering Failure

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rendering, toolbar

I have implemented a ToolBar and styling according to the following style. For the images I am using vector graphics from an .xaml resource file

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                          xmlns:Caliburn="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <Rectangle x:Key="ToolBarButtonIcon" 
                  x:Shared="False" 
                  Visibility="{Binding IconVisibility}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Width="16" Height="16">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{Binding IconSource}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarToggleButton" 
             TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonIcon}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipText}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ToolTipServiceEnabled}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        <Setter Property="Caliburn:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Caliburn:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarButton" 
             TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonIcon}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipText}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ToolTipServiceEnabled}"/>
        <Setter Property="Caliburn:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Caliburn:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This renders the ToolBar great and all looks well

---

### [image: Okay]

But not if I drag one ToolBar group over the other the images disappear and I get

---

### [image: Error]

I am aware of the use of `x:Shared="False"` on the image source, but this is not helping me in this case. What can I do to force my `ToolBar` to render correctly?

Note. I have also tried setting all the `Virtualizing` properties on each off the components I though could impact this and this did not help.

Thanks for your time.

---

### Solution:

Thanks to @Mike Strobel, I have a solution. It was to change the style of each button to reference their own `Rectangle` image container. Silly not to spot this, but in the end the styles became

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarToggleButton" 
         TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle x:Shared="False" 
                              Visibility="{Binding IconVisibility}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              Width="16" Height="16">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipText}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ToolTipServiceEnabled}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    <Setter Property="Caliburn:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Caliburn:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ToolBarButton" 
         TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle x:Shared="False" 
                              Visibility="{Binding IconVisibility}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              Width="16" Height="16">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipText}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ToolTipServiceEnabled}"/>
    <Setter Property="Caliburn:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Caliburn:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}"/>
</Style>
```

I hope this helps someone else.

---

### Additional Binding Errors for ToolTip

I have changed the style again to avoid the tool tip bindings also failing upon the `ToolBarItems` container being dragged. The issue now is that the tool tip only pops-up when hovering over the rectangle containing the image and not when over the button surface...

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarButton" 
             TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Transparent"
                              ToolTip="{Binding FullToolTip}"
                              ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding HasToolTip}">
                        <Rectangle x:Shared="False" 
                                  Visibility="{Binding IconVisibility}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                  Width="16" Height="16">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Caliburn:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Caliburn:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}"/>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style assigns the same `Rectangle` instance to each button's `Content`, but WPF will not allow you to host the same visual in more than one visual tree.  Try using a `ContentTemplate` to specify the button's visual tree instead.

Comment: thanks for your advice above. But I have another problem; although the above fixed the images, the `ToolTip` bindings also fail as well as the bindings to the `Caliburn` properties when the `ToolBar` is dragged. I can solve the tool tip issue by including the tool tip on the rectangle or wrapping the rectangle in a `ContentControl` and adding the tool tip to that, but this does not work for the Caliburn properties and also means that the tool tip does not show for mouse hover at the very edge of the button. Could you advice on potential ways to fix this?

Comment: You may be able to fix the tool tip issue by wrapping the `Rectangle` in a `Border` with `Background="Transparent"`.  This ensures there is a rectangular hit-testable region filling the content area.  I'm not familiar with Caliburn, so I can't advise on those properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Merely adding it on the rectangle does solve the binding problem, just as it did with the image problem, it is just not the hit-test region for the tool-tip is only on the rectangle/border and does not cover the entire button surface, this is minor, but it would be nice to know how to get this to work... Any further ideas?

Comment: That's odd.  The `ToolTipService` should walk the tree and pick up the `ToolTip` from the styled `Button` when the cursor is positioned over any part of the button's content.  You should not need to explicitly set the `ToolTip` anywhere in the template.  Check and make sure you aren't setting a local `ToolTip` value directly on the button (which would supersede the value set by the style)?

Comment: Definitely don't set the tool tip elsewhere. I find this entire behavior odd. I understand the issue I first had with the image in a `StaticResource`, but all I am now doing is setting the tooltip in a style and this gets broken by using the drag features of this control!? I suppose I can live with what I have, but it would be nice to know why this binding corruption is occurring...

Comment: Did you say that you're using some kind of third-party drag and drop behavior?  If so, that code may be the culprit, as it may be swallowing input events when it shouldn't, or it may capturing the mouse and never releasing the capture.  That sort of functionality is tricky to get right.